# using javascript in angular typescript component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use the `region` variable inside the callback however there is no way I can get the value of it.

As you might be already aware I am instantiating a JS objects using TS and the callback is part of the definition of this JS object.

I am already being able to use JS in my Angular components using `() => {` in those methods where I need to use any reference to 'this' inside JS callbacks but for this particular case it does not work at all.

```
showRegion = (region: string) => {
        var service = new JS.service();
        var prov = new JS.provider(service, {
            callback: (data) => {
                // cannot read region variable
            }
    })
```

Thanks,

Comment: JS here represent what class?

Comment: It's a JS object from a external JS library.    const JS= window['JS'];

Comment: And this JS has method service()?
Can you post some code of your JS const?

Comment: Your title is not really appropriate, it's more a scope problem (was expecting "typescript IS javascript" answers from people not reading the question, still none though). Do you have the same issue using a classic function syntax for `callback`, or a closure? By the way, do you get expected result when displaying `region` inside `showRegion`?

Comment: Well, this a third party library "heremaps", I have change the names of the variables for simplicity. Yes. service and provider exists and they work when I am not using this region var. The only thing that I cannot do is getting/using region variable on the callback defined on the json as a constructor parameter for provider.

Comment: @Kaddath  Yes I can use region inside showRegion but not inside the callback.

Comment: @AitorMolina you need to read about TypeScript. You can start at http://typescriptlang.org. You should know that there is no such thing, for example, as TypeScript <=> JavaScript interop because TypeScript _is_ JavaScript.

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please, provide a way to replicate this error. `region` exists and can't toggle error like `cannot read region variable` if `callback` was called regularly and not with `eval`.

Comment: The problem may be in `JS.provider` rather than in the shown code. If i use a classic function syntax to emulate a JS object with things you are using inside, i have no problem to get `region`. [See example here](https://jsfiddle.net/maz2grgh/)